# Quais os tipos de retain cycles que se podem gerar com ARC?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memória

Eu sei que com ARC pode haver leaks em iOS. Quais os tipos de leaks mais frequentes e como podem ser evitados?

Answer (score 8):

O principal problema relacionado a memória são os ciclos de `retain`. Eles ocorrem quando um objeto possui um ponteiro `strong` para um segundo objeto, e este possui um ponteiro `strong` para o primeiro. Mesmo quando todas as referências a esses objetos são removidas, eles ainda referenciam um ao outro e não serão desalocados. Isso também pode ocorrer indiretamente, através de uma cadeia de objetos cujo último na cadeia se refere ao primeiro.

Para entender esse tipo de problema, é importante saber como funciona o gerenciamento de memória no iOS. Não há *garbage collector*; em vez disso, é usado o mecanismo de contagem de referências. Cada ponteiro `strong` adiciona 1 ao contador de referências do objeto apontado (diz-se, nesse caso, que o ponteiro *retém* o objeto). Quando o ponteiro deixa de apontar para o objeto, o contador de referências do objeto é decrementado em uma unidade (diz-se qu o ponteiro *solta* o objeto). O objeto é desalocado quando seu contador de referências chega a zero.

É por isso que existem os modificadores `__unsafe_unretained` e `__weak`. O `__unsafe_unretained` não retém o objeto para o qual aponta (i.e., não incrementa o contador de referências do objeto), mas se o objeto for desalocado, o ponteiro apontará para memória inválida. O `__weak` não retém o objeto e altera o ponteiro para `nil` quando o objeto é desalocado. Esses modificadores são usados para apontar para *delegates*, pois em geral você não quer que um objeto retenha seu delegate, o que poderia levar a um ciclo.

Outro ponto importante é que o ARC não gerencia a memória de tipos em C, como aqueles do framework Core Foundation (ex.: `CGImageRef`), que são alocados usando `malloc()` (ou através de uma função que chama `malloc()`). Você é responsável por gerenciar a memória desses objetos de forma a evitar vazamentos de memória.

(Baseado em https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260256/what-kind-of-leaks-does-automatic-reference-counting-in-objective-c-not-prevent)

Answer (score 2):

O ARC é uma grande ajuda para resolver problemas de vazamento de memória, porém, isso não significa que o programador está livre de responsabilidades em relação a isso. Enquanto há uma referência strong apontando para um objeto ele estará vivo (gastando memória).

Isso significa que pode ser interessante remover todas as referências fortes de um objeto (object = nil), para que ele morra num determinado instante ao invés de deixar ele morrer no fim da aplicação.

Também é importante utilizar referências  do tipo weak sempre que possível para evitar esse tipo de problema.

Se não houver esses cuidados os objetos ficarão vivos para sempre, mesmo quando totalmente inúteis para o progama.

Answer (score 1):

Ignorando por um momento a parte teórica, que já foi bem discutida pelas demais respostas, você pode ter uma visão mais prática desses problemas (ao menos em níveis mais básicos) executando o `Clang Static Analyzer` através do próprio `Xcode`.

Essa ferramenta não deve ser utilizada como resposta definitiva para os problemas, mas pode apresentar uma visão inicial dos pontos mais críticos do seu aplicativo.

`XCode` > `Product` > `Analyze` 
(Preferencialmente com o `target/scheme` setado para `device`).

Answer (score 0):

Outro problema comum tem a ver com os blocos, por exemplo se temos um propriedade numa classe que referencia um bloco e logo dentro do bloco usamos self podemos criar um referencia circular.

```objectivec
@property (nonatomic, copy) MyBlock block;

self.block = ^{
                NSLog(@"object is %@", self); // retain cycle
            };

__weak me = self; 
self.block = ^{
                    NSLog(@"object is %@", me); // no retain cycle
                };
```